# Method does not return anything

Tags: java, android, firebase, null, google-cloud-firestore

I have a java class containing a method `CheckForUpdate()` that has a return type of `String`. Call to this method is initiated from my `activity class`. This method assigns the fetched `String` value to my `class` variable named `link`. Inside the `if` block variable `link` shows the fetched `String`. But in the return statement it returns `null`. Why is that?

**Java Class:**

```
public class method_class {

    Context context;

    public String link;
    boolean b;

    public FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    public FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //constructor
    public method_class(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String CheckForUpdate()
    {
        firestore.collection("Admin").document("appinfo")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

                    String version = documentSnapshot.getString("version");

                    final String in_app_version = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;

                    if(!TextUtils.equals(version, in_app_version))
                    {
                        //update available
                        link = documentSnapshot.getString("link");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //no update
                        link = null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share piece of code you have try yet so far.

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry. I forgot to put my code. I added it now.

Comment: @Shane Sorry. I forgot to put my code. It's added now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase methods are asynchronous, your method is basically returning the result before the listener fetches an event. Instead you should use the result once your onComplete fires with successful task instead of returning a String with the method

Comment: But the return statement does not work inside the successful task portion.

Comment: @Sajib what Kushan explains is that your return statement is already executed before successful task is executed. You need a return statement for each possible scenario. You'll need to read up on (a)synchronous methods.

Comment: Also `link` is a field so the method doesn't need to return anything

Comment: dont return the answer from within onComplete, i am saying use it however you like from inside that scope. Eg you can print it inside there and you will see the value if your listener is correct. If your listener isn't working then thats a separate issue

Comment: @Kushan I understood your point. My listener is working fine. Just I am not getting the link value with the return statement.

Comment: you won't... Basically the return statement gets executed before the asynchronous operation finishes. It is by design that this works that way. If you still wish to make is synchronous, you might want to look into Tasks API of google. I would advise against it as it will end up blocking your UI thread but then that's your choice :) happy coding... accept the answer if it is satisfactory

Comment: basically something like Tasks.await(task); will cause your task to be synchronous and then your link will return a value but i am advising against this.... please do not do this to yourself, trust me i've been burned before

Comment: @Kushan okay. Mybe I can use some time delay before the return statement executes.

Comment: Not a reliable method... just update whatever you need to from inside the onComplete buddy, that's your best bet.... delays may be too late or too early and they basically destroy the "Real-Time" of firebase

Comment: @Kushan delay does not work. I will use this method in different activity class. That's why I have written it in a separate class so that I don't have to write it again and again for each activity class. And for different activity class I will perform different intent calling based on the returned value.

Comment: if you want the result only once, why not use the REST API and fetch the data as a normal http call?

Comment: @Kushan But I want to call the method many times.And I don't have knowledge about REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You are using listener to read data. So your method returns link with null value before listener finishes data reading. You should wait listener then return link.